# The '#' char gets converted to %23 causing the GET Request to fail

Tags: ios, url, swift3

I am a new Swift developer using Swift 3 developing an iOS app.  I need to make a URL Request to get some data from the web.  That URL contains a `#` character.

I use `URLComponents` with `URLQueryItems` to build the request URL.  During this process the `#` char gets converted to `%23` which I think is valid utf8 encoding.  Unfortunately, this causes the GET to fail.

To test I pasted the URL into my browser and changed `%23` back to `#` and it worked just fine.

How can I fix this so it does not change `#` to URL.  I did find a post from a couple years ago but it was using old framework items so it does not apply to me.

Below is the playground I made to illustrate and test this.

```
// ------------------------------------------------------------------
//: Playground - TestBuildURLWithParameters
//
// I am using this playground to build the proper
// URL for the GET request to get the detailed 
// rtesults for a specific athlete where the "Key"
// is their Bib Nbr. If the GET cant find the specific
// Atlete with that URL it redirects you to the list
// of athlete results (which is no go to me in this case)
//
// Currently, there is a big "gotcha".  In building the URL
// using component and query items, the foundation classes
// replace the '#' sign in the URL with the %23 which represents
// the pound sign.  Unfortunately, the causes the GET to fail
// and redirects to athlete list which is not helpful
// I am still trying to figure out how to FORCE it to keep
// the '#" character in the URL so it will work
//
// ------------------------------------------------------------------

import Foundation
import UIKit

let baseURLString = "http://www.ironman.com/triathlon/events/americas/ironman-70.3/augusta/results.aspx"
let rd = "20150927"
let race = "augusta70.3"
let bibID = "93"
var detail = "1#axzz4FGGcjBOn"
print("Detail w/o unicocde: \(detail)")

detail = "1\u{0023}axzz4FGGcjBOn"
print("Detail with unicocde: \(detail)")


var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString)!

var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = []     // All Items after the "?"

let baseParams =
[
    "rd": rd,
    "race": race,
    "bidID": bibID,     //  Note: HTML mispelled bib with bid so "bidID" is the URL search
    "detail": detail
]

for (key, value) in baseParams
{
    let item = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
    queryItems.append(item)
}

components.queryItems = queryItems          // what does this look like
print("components: \(components)")          // see it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good way to include [fragment part](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) of URL into query items.

Try this:

```
import Foundation

let baseURLString = "http://www.ironman.com/triathlon/events/americas/ironman-70.3/augusta/results.aspx"
let rd = "20150927"
let race = "augusta70.3"
let bibID = "93"
var detail = "1"
//# split the last query item and the fragment
let fragment = "axzz4FGGcjBOn"

var components = URLComponents(string: baseURLString)!

var queryItems: [URLQueryItem] = []

let baseParams =
    [
        "rd": rd,
        "race": race,
        "bidID": bibID,
        "detail": detail
]

for (key, value) in baseParams
{
    let item = URLQueryItem(name: key, value: value)
    queryItems.append(item)
}

components.queryItems = queryItems
components.fragment = fragment
print("components: \(components)")
```

Comment: Thanks.  I did not realize that the # split the actual query item and a fragment .  Of course I didn't know what a fragment is so....  I will try this and let you know, but it certainly looks like a good approach

Comment: WOW.  Thank you so much.  It works and this is definitely the correct way to do it.  I appreciate your help a great deal.

Answer (score 0):

If you need you can choose the character that will receive the encoding.
In the charactersIn: you put all characters you want to encode.
Then you use the .inverted so all the others characters will go normal  like this:

```
let customAllowedSet =  NSCharacterSet(charactersIn:"=\"%/<>?@\\^`{|}").inverted
let encondedString = originalString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: customAllowedSet)

print("enconded string: \(encondedString)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your parameters and then add it to URL, this will encode # before hitting API and you'll get desired result.

To encode parameters, you can use below code.

```
var parameterString = "your parameter string"
var encodedString = parameterString .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
print(encodedString !)
```

Comment: Thanks.  Maybe I used it wrong, but it ended up converted the # to %23 after the encoding and then when adding query items it morphed %23 into %2523 by the time is was added to URL.  I used your code to encode the detail string before it got added to the query items and then the URL using:  var detailEncodedString = detail.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)
print(detailEncodedString!)

Answer (score 0):

I did get an answer via email from a friend that works for now.  Basically, I added the query items manually to the URL using the URL extension below so it didn't monkey with the '#' char:

```
    extension URL {

        func appendingNonEscapedQueryItems(_ queryItems: [URLQueryItem]) -> URL {
            let url = self
            var urlString = url.absoluteString
            for queryItem in queryItems {
                let queryName = queryItem.name
                guard let queryValue = queryItem.value else {
                    continue
                }

                let query = queryName + "=" + queryValue
                if queryItem == queryItems.first {
                    urlString = urlString + "?" + query
                }
                else
                {
                    urlString = urlString + "&" + query
                }
            }
            return URL(string: urlString)!
        }

    }
...
let requestURL = components.url!.appendingNonEscapedQueryItems(queryItems)
print("URL \(requestURL)")
```