# Pound/hash signs being converted by Teams into %23

Tags: microsoft-teams

My bot sends links to my employees in various types of cards according to the following format:

```
$card["content"]["items"][] = array(
  "type" => "resultItem",
  ...
  "tap" => array(
    "type" => "openUrl",
    "value" => "https://.../#Path/...",
  ),
);
```

The problem is the # in the link. It turns into `https://.../%23Path/...` when the user taps on the item. Interestingly, it works as expected in the browser and desktop versions of Teams, but not in the mobile version. In other words, from the first two platforms clicking the item will successfully open the page in the browser with the # in the link, but mobile browsers are given %23 by Teams, which does not work.

How do I prevent Teams from replacing the #?

Comment: It is not recommended to include [fragment](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) part of URL into query items. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42469764/the-char-gets-converted-to-23-causing-the-get-request-to-fail) thread which is in similar line.

Comment: The # is part of the URL and I can't change that (it's a vendor service). The Microsoft documentation does not say how to add the 'query parameters' (the rest of the URL string) to the `value` field in the `tap` array. The information in the other thread does not help with this situation because what can be sent to the Teams back-end is not customizable. There is nothing in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/task-modules-and-cards/cards/cards-reference#list-card) link that shows how to do what you're saying. The only option is to send the whole URL.

Comment: Please refer this [thread](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/apar/IV05135) and check if it helps.